# OpenGraph being blocked by AuthContext

Tags: next.js, seo, facebook-opengraph

I have had real issues last day or two trying to get my OpenGraph tags to work in my NextJS site. I have always got them to work before and after a lot of research I think it's due to me having a loading state in my AuthContext that blocks the rendering of the components until the user is received.

If I remove the loading state it breaks the build. Sorry I know this isn't the easiest issue to resolve but does anyone have a way I can stop blocking my SEO stuff and still keep my authorisation in place?

**context/AuthContextProvider.js**

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import {
    ..., onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';

import { auth } from '../config/firebase';
import OpenGraph from '../components/OpenGraph';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            if (user) {
                setCurrentUser(user);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });

        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    const signup = async data => {
        ...
    };

    const login = async (email, password) => {
        ...
    };

    const forgottenPassword = async email => {
        ...
    };

    const updateUser = async (displayName, photoURL) => {
        ...
    };

    const verifyEmail = async () => {
        ...
    };

    const changeEmail = async (password, email) => {
        ...
    };

    const changePassword = async (currentPassword, newPassword) => {
        ...
    };

    const logout = async () => {
        ...
    };

    const deleteAccount = async password => {
        ...
    };

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup,
        login,
        forgottenPassword,
        updateUser,
        changeEmail,
        changePassword,
        verifyEmail,
        logout,
        deleteAccount,
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children /* ← i think this is the issue} */}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

**components/OpenGraph.js**

```js
import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';
import { linkResolver } from '../prismicio';

const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

const OpenGraph = ({ page, settings }) => {
    return (
        <NextSeo
            openGraph={{
                locale: 'en_IE',
                site_name: `${settings?.data?.businessName[0]?.text}`,
                url: `${baseURL + linkResolver(page)}`,
                title: `${page?.data?.meta_title}`,
                description: `${page?.data?.meta_description}`,
                images: [
                    {
                        url: `${page?.data?.social_card?.url}`,
                        width: `${page?.data?.social_card?.dimensions?.width}`,
                        height: `${page?.data?.social_card?.dimensions?.height}`,
                        alt: `${page?.data?.social_card?.alt || page?.data?.title}`,
                    },
                ],
            }}
            twitter={{
                handle: `@${settings?.data?.twitter}`,
                site: `@${settings?.data?.twitter}`,
                cardType: 'summary_large_image',
            }}
        />
    );
};

export default OpenGraph;
```

**hooks/withProtected.js**

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import React from 'react';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';

import { useAuth } from '../context/AuthContext';

export default function withProtected(Component) {
    return function WithProtected(props) {
        const { currentUser } = useAuth();
        const router = useRouter();

        if (!currentUser) {
            router.push('/login');
            return (
                <div className='h-96 min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center'>
                    <Loader title='Redirecting...' />
                </div>
            );
        }

        return <Component currentUser={currentUser} {...props} />;
    };
}
```

**pages/dashboard.js**

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from 'react';

import { NextSeo } from 'next-seo';
import { createClient } from '../prismicio';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { Tab } from '@headlessui/react';

import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import withProtected from '../hooks/withProtected';
import { Profile } from '../components/SVGs';
import ProfileForm from '../components/ProfileForm';
import DeleteForm from '../components/DeleteForm';
import EmailForm from '../components/EmailForm';
import PasswordForm from '../components/PasswordForm';
import OpenGraph from '../components/OpenGraph';

const Dashboard = ({ page, menu, settings }) => {
    const { currentUser } = getAuth();

    const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState(currentUser?.displayName);
    const [photoURL, setPhotoURL] = useState(currentUser?.photoURL);

    return (
        <>
            <NextSeo
                title={page.data.meta_title}
                description={page.data.meta_description}
            />
            <OpenGraph page={page} settings={settings} />
            <Layout settings={settings} menu={menu} pageUid={page?.uid}>
                <section className='mt-32 mb-20 container'>
                    ...
                </section>
            </Layout>
        </>
    );
};

export async function getStaticProps({ previewData }) {
    const client = createClient({ previewData });

    const page = await client.getSingle('dashboard');
    const menu = await client.getSingle('menu');
    const settings = await client.getSingle('settings');

    return {
        props: { page, menu, settings },
        revalidate: 60,
    };
}

export default withProtected(Dashboard);
```

When viewing page source all the opengraph tags are displaying perfectly but it seems they are pulled from the server and because of the loading state in my AuthContext, the children are not being prebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. I’ve removed context from app and am using react-firebase-hooks instead so only hide necessary parts of page rather than whole pages.